# Issues with R lang and lifecycle versions

Tags: r

I am trying to knit an Rmarkdown document (up until now I have never had any issues) but i get the following error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace 'lifecycle' 1.0.0 is being loaded but >= 1.0.1 is required Execution halted

After trying to re-install lifecycle with the following command

```
devtools::install_github("r-lib/lifecycle")
```

I get a simmilar error with rlang:

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’

- removing ‘/Users/name/Library/R/4.0/library/lifecycle’
  Error: Failed to install 'lifecycle' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/gj/xz0j3hnd6z9gxbs79ply8nm00000gn/T//RtmpotiD17/filee36f2c2ec74/lifecycle_1.0.3.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I think there is an issue with the versions of my packages but I do not know how to solve it / why this has suddenly occurred.

Comment: Restart R. Make sure no packages are loaded. Then try to upload those packages. Run `install.packages("rlang")` and `install.packages("lifecycle")` You just have to make sure they aren't already loaded before trying to update them.

Comment: I still get an error. * installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’

Comment: I don't know what the issue was but I ended up uninstalling R and R studio (and deleting the related libraries from my computer) and re installing them. All is fixed now.